# Multiple font-families for bidi text

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, fonts, bidi

I have unmarked bidi text like

```
<span>The verb קָרָא has no expressed subject</span>
```

I want to style it (in the browser) depending on its direction: That is, I want a Hebrew font for the Hebrew and an English font for the English. I don't suppose there's any way of doing it based on whether it's `ltr` or `rtl` when it's not marked but perhaps there's some way using unicode ranges or something.

I could use `regex` to put spans around text that falls in particular unicode ranges but I'm hoping for a CSS only solution (or one that doesn't involve extra markup - it's user generated text and the user needs to be able to modify it as well).

Something like (I know this doesn't exist):

```
.bidi-text {
    font-family-rtl: "EZRA SIL"
    font-family-ltr: "Comic Sans"
}
```

Otherwise, maybe there's a better js solution? Or some way to tell the browser to use certain fonts for certain glyps?